# Alphabet riddle

Tags: letters

For the sake of this question, the alphabet repeats itself after the letter "Z" and/or before the letter "A"

What comes after the letters "H", "G", and the letter "Z" but before the letter "B".

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Based on the current phrasing wouldn't every letter appear before and after every over letter since it repeats? May just need an edit to further clarify what you mean. Also if you'd like to learn more about the site and get your first badge, check out the tour: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

> Letter A?

Though I have to point out that

> Since the alphabet wraps around, every letter comes both before and after every other letter.